# When editing and submiting the document properties using editform.aspx page,the document itself is opening

Tags: document-library, edit-form

When I edit the properties of a document using the `editform.aspx?Id=Id` page, after submission the document gets opened.

What should be done to resolve/avoid this?

To be much more clear.

I have a workflow associated with a document library and i hyperlink the URL,
**`http//server/site/documentlibrary/forms/editform.aspx?Id=[id]`** for the approvers to update the document properties.

Once they update the properties and clicks **`OK`** ,the document gets opened.

How to avoid/resolve this behaviour?